# Styles don't load correctly. Insecure content

Tags: plugin-development, css

I'm a newby developing plugins for Wordpress.

When I try to enqueue a style, Wordpress shows the following error: Insecure Content.

The code I use to 'attach' the css files is the following one:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');

function callback_for_setting_up_scripts(){
  wp_register_style('estilo', __DIR__ . '/assets/css/estilo.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'estilo' );
}
```

This code is located in the `/modules` folder of the main plugin because it's the style for a specific module.

I use Query Monitor Plugin as a debugger.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__DIR__` returns the current file system path, not a URL. So the resulting stylesheet will not be a valid URL, and will not have `https://`, causing the insecure content warning.

To get the URL for a stylesheet in your plugin, you need to use [`plugins_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/):

```
wp_register_style( 'estilo', plugins_url( 'assets/css/estilo.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

The use of `__FILE__` here is described in the documentation for the function:

> A full path to a file inside a plugin or mu-plugin. The URL will be
>   relative to its directory. Typically this is done by passing `__FILE__`
>   as the argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was my problem. Thanks!